# Invalid survival times for this distribution

Tags: r, survival

I'm using survreg function in R and

```
survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ variables, rain,dist="lognormal")
```

gives me   Invalid survival times for this distribution.
The name of variable is indeed time and it doesn't contain negative values.

Answer (score 19):

The `survreg` function in R does not allow `time = 0`. This is because for several of the distributions, including the lognormal distribution, having events occur at time = 0 will result in an undefined estimator.

You can think that having `time = 0` for a lognormal would be similar to having `y = -Inf` for a normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a lot of zeros in my data. Does this mean that I should remove zeros (or change them to a very small value like 0.00001) or I can use a different distribution?

Comment: That's a little tricky. The reason for this is it will have a large impact if you switch 0's for 0.1 or 0.000001. To properly answer your question, it helps to know why you have some many zeros.